# Trouble getting android logo into the action bar

Tags: android, icons

All I want is the logo that I specified in the manifest (ic_launcher.png) next to the name of the activity. It shows up as an icon for the launcher but not in the menu. I have pointed the logo and icon attribute to this one image in the manifest. I am using the getMenuInflater() in a OnCreateOptionMenu to fill a menu on top of the screen. That has been working fine. I set it up so that the user can click and move through different activities of the application. The name of the application shows up but the icon does not in that bar.

My manifest has the logo:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

When I put this code in to enable, the program crashes. Why?

```
    ActionBar actionBar= getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

[On android's own developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) it says:

> Using a logo instead of an icon
>
> By default, the system uses your application icon in the action bar,
>   as specified by the icon attribute in the  or 
>   element. However, if you also specify the logo attribute, then the
>   action bar uses the logo image instead of the icon.

I also tried running it directly with the same result:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

The crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at .MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
```

It's pointing at the above statement.

I also tried:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

The app doesn't crash with this but there is no logo.

I have `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as my apps theme and I believe that this takes my icon away.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

I am extending `ActionBarActivity`and inflating the menu `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);`

I am extending the ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Post the error you are getting

Comment: Do you use appcompat-v7? Which version?

Comment: Try using getSupportActionBar() instead

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I did. No crashing but there is also no logo.

Comment: @Mattia I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: try this : getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one problems with your code.

Since you are using ActionBarActivity and AppCompat, you have to understand what exactly it means when you use  ActionBarActivity.

You haven't posted your code so It's not clear if you are using Toolbar or ActionBar (ActionBar has deprecated and you shouldn't be using if you are still using.)

If you are already using Toolbar then you can set icon like this.

> ```
>     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>     if (toolbar != null) {
>         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
>         toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.icon_here);
>     }
> ```

If you are not using Toolbar then set these lines in your theme first.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

<!-- following two lines -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

And then in your activity layout file add toolbar at the top.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
```

Comment: This shows up in both the activities I am using but is only clickable in my main activity (I have strings as shortcuts in the actionbar). It is not in my other activity.

Comment: What shows up in both activities? Update your question to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this issue is caused by the fact that you're using the 21.+ or 22.+ version of support library. Starting from Lollipop, the use of app logo in `ActionBar` is discouraged, and the newest versions of support library reflect this change.

If you still wish to use app logo in `ActionBar`, you'll need to add `Toolbar` view to your layout (more info on this view can be found [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)) and use one of its `setLogo()` methods: [first](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(int)) or [second](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

Comment: What if I am already extending ActionBar and using MenuInflator?

Comment: @munchschair well, if you don't want to use Toolbar, one option would be to set targetSdkVersion & support libraries version to 19. you'll see your logo again. But your app will look Holo-styled on Lollipop devices. If you can deal with it, target your app for KitKat devices.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest you use **android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"** for the application instead.(try **@drawable**)

If it doesn't work , try `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`
(should be call before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`)

By the way ,if you wanna specify a icon for every different Activity, you can also set **android:logo="@drawable/YOUR_ICON"** in Activity

Hope it works

Comment: Why drawable instead of mipmap?

Comment: maybe it works?see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: First doesn't work. Second makes the program crash. I added the crash up there ^.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/mainColor500</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This crashes as well. (I did not include mainColor500).

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html), `mipmap` folder is for application icons, but not saying application logo also be ok. So I suppose you better set logo from drawable folder:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:logo="@drawable/...."`   to the Application section of your Manifest file.

[android:logo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)
    A logo for the application as whole, and the default logo for activities.

This attribute must be set as a reference to a drawable resource containing the image (for example "@drawable/logo"). There is no default logo.

Comment: Oh wait, does it have to be drawable? I have it in mipmap.